# Pandas: calculate overlapping with pivot_table or crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to make overlapping with some data from a dataframe.
Here a quick example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
'player':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'], 
'game':['gameA', 'gameB', 'gameC', 'gameC', 'gameB', 'gameD', 'gameA']})
```

df:

```
    game player
0  gameA      A
1  gameB      B
2  gameC      C
3  gameC      D
4  gameB      A
5  gameD      C
6  gameA      B
```

What I want to do is calculate the number of player which are in two games for each combination.

for example the result should look like this:

```
   game1 game2   overlap
  gameA  gameB        2 #Because there is 2 players who play at gameA and gameB
  gameA  gameC        0
  gameA  gameD        0
  gameB  gameA        2         
  gameB  gameC        0
  gameB  gameD        0          
  ...
```

I can do this with a dictionnary and a foreach but is there a simple way to do it with pivot_table or a crosstab ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.merge` to create `game_table`:

```
game_table = pd.merge(df, df, how='left', on=['player'])
#    game_x player game_y
# 0   gameA      A  gameA
# 1   gameA      A  gameB
# 2   gameB      B  gameB
# 3   gameB      B  gameA
# 4   gameC      C  gameC
# 5   gameC      C  gameD
# 6   gameC      D  gameC
# 7   gameB      A  gameA
# 8   gameB      A  gameB
# 9   gameD      C  gameC
# 10  gameD      C  gameD
# 11  gameA      B  gameB
# 12  gameA      B  gameA
```

then apply `pd.crosstab` to `game_table`:

```
freq = pd.crosstab(game_table['game_x'], game_table['game_y'])
# game_y  gameA  gameB  gameC  gameD
# game_x                            
# gameA       2      2      0      0
# gameB       2      2      0      0
# gameC       0      0      2      1
# gameD       0      0      1      1
```

`stack` followed by `reset_index` reshapes the DataFrame into the desired form:

```
result = freq.stack().reset_index()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'player':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B'], 
     'game':['gameA', 'gameB', 'gameC', 'gameC', 'gameB', 'gameD', 'gameA']})

game_table = pd.merge(df, df, how='left', on=['player'])
freq = pd.crosstab(game_table['game_x'], game_table['game_y'])
result = freq.stack()
result.name = 'overlap'
result = result.reset_index()
mask = (result['game_x'] != result['game_y'])
result = result.loc[mask]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   game_x game_y  overlap
1   gameA  gameB        2  # Because both A and B played in gameA and gameB
2   gameA  gameC        0
3   gameA  gameD        0
4   gameB  gameA        2
6   gameB  gameC        0
7   gameB  gameD        0
8   gameC  gameA        0
9   gameC  gameB        0
11  gameC  gameD        1
12  gameD  gameA        0
13  gameD  gameB        0
14  gameD  gameC        1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing the freq.stack() part.